# Unit Test is skipping all break points

Tags: c#, unit-testing, testing, breakpoints

I've created a class with a funcion and than I've created a unit test to test it.
I've than updated somethings on my class and referenced the dll to it on the UnitTest after building the class after the changes.
When I run the unit test in debug mode it skips every break point thats on the fucntion in the class, but when I put a break point in the UnitTest it self it shows me an error message saying that the module has change since last time, even after I reference it again.
What is wrong? Do I need to rebuild the class and than reference it in the test?

Comment: Clean. If it does not work close and reopen visual studio

Comment: I sometimes get this outside of a unit test. The way I fix it is to Clean the solution, close Visual Studio, make sure the app isn't being hosted in IIS Manger (if an ASP.Net app), reopen, rebuild.

Comment: Also do Remove All Break points ( Ctrl+Shift+F9 ) by default). It seems like if you set a break point, then comment out the code where the break point is set. Sometimes it appears the debugger gets confused

Comment: @NexTerren that solved my problem, I wish to close this question, please provide an answer

Comment: Provided an answer. Glad that fixed your issue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sometimes get this outside of a unit test. The way I fix this is to:

1. Clean the solution
2. Close Visual Studio
3. Ensure the app isn't hosted in IIS Manager (if an ASP.Net app)
4. Reopen the solution
5. Rebuild the solution